# Adding new rows by summing dividing existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm connecting to MySql database on Tableau through a sql query. I have a table with three columns (DateTime, Compteur, Valeur). What I want to do is adding new rows by adding/multiplying/dividing the existing rows.

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|     DateTime        |     Compteur     |      Valeur
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         A        |       5
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:57:42|         A        |       6
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:52:14|         B        |       NULL
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         B        |       8
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 16:51:30|         C        |       5
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:57:42|         C        |       6
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------
|  15.04.2019 16:52:14|         D        |       8
|---------------------|------------------|----------------- 
|  15.04.2019 17:52:14|         D        |       9
|---------------------|------------------|---------------- 
|       (NEW ROW)
  15.04.2019 16:00:00 |      K           |       3.0769
|---------------------|------------------|---------------- 
|       (NEW ROW)
  15.04.2019 17:00:00 |      K           |       8.4
|---------------------|------------------|----------------
```

The goal is to do the following: (A+B)/(C+D)*D. The calculation should be done for each hour and added as a new row with a a new compteur name in string. Null values should be treated as zero in the calculations. Could you provide a generic code which could do what I want. Thanks in advance!

This is already what I have to receive the data from the database. I'm calculating the difference since the values are accumulated so I have to find the value for corresponding DateTime by substracting from the previous row in each Compteur:

```
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur
FROM
(
    SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
    ,       Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY DateTime) AS Valeur
    FROM History 
    WHERE  TagName IN 
                    (
                     'H270ME01MDB90.vol',
                    'H270ME01MDB91.vol',
                    'HA44AC01CDI07.vol',
                    'HA44AC01CDI06.vol',
                    ) 
    AND DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00'
    AND wwRetrievalMode='Delta'
)t
WHERE t.DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE and a `UNION ALL` that does the calculation you want:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur
      FROM (SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
    ,               Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY DateTime) AS Valeur
            FROM History 
            WHERE TagName IN ('H270ME01MDB90.vol', 'H270ME01MDB91.vol', 'HA44AC01CDI07.vol', 'HA44AC01CDI06.vol',
                              )  AND
                  DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00' AND
                  wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
           ) t
       WHERE t.DateTime >= '2019-01-01'  -- seems simpler
      )
SELECT t.*
FROM t
UNION ALL
(SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATETIME) / 3600) * 3600) as hour,
        'K' as compteur,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('A', 'B') THEN Valeur END) /
         SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('C', 'D') THEN Valeur
             END)
        ) * SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('D') THEN Valeur END)
 FROM t
 GROUP BY hour
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very quick answer! If I want to do the same calculations for another new row, should I add a new UNION ALL body?

Comment: I implemented your code but it throws an error by saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Comment: @sgokce . . . If you database supports `LAG()`, then it supports `WITH`.  But, you can repeat the CTE as a subquery in the second query.

Comment: I added a semicolon just before the with statement and now it says "Incorrect syntax near ';'". If I don't put it it says:"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon." I don't understand the issue

Comment: Now I'm able to create the CTE perfectly but UNIX_TIMESTAMP and UNIXTIME are causing an error as the following: 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' is not a recognized built-in function name.